# React Native Google Places Autocomplete radius restriction not working

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm hoping to restrict the Google Places search results to 20 miles around my users current location.

Adding the radius parameter to the query isn't working at all. Here's my code:

```
          query={{
    // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
    key: 'AIzaSyCMFiyTGVGJQgi1AOShIuRppi9JqcSgobw',
    language: 'en', // language of the results
    types: ['street_address', 'establishment'], // default: 'geocode'
    components: 'country:us'
    latitude: 32.795969,
      longitude: -80.028863,
      radius: 100
  }}
  styles={locationAutocompleteStyle}

  currentLocation={false} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
  currentLocationLabel="Current location"
  nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
  GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
    // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
  }}
  GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
    // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
    // rankby: 'distance',
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The radius you have provided is taken in metres and it should be a string

You can try this

```
     <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                            placeholder='search'
                            minLength={2}
                            autoFocus={true}
                            returnKeyType={'default'}
                            fetchDetails={true}
                            query={{
                                key: '***********8',
                                language: 'es', // language of the results
                                location: '20.8840744, -100.7607736',
                                radius: '15000', //15 km
                                components:'country:mx',
                                strictbounds: true,
                            }}
    />
```